# Why doesn't this Haskell typeclass code work?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Trying to figure out Haskell typeclasses.  Why doesn't the following work?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class IntClass t
instance IntClass Int

intToIntClass  :: (IntClass r) => Int -> r
intToIntClass  x = x
```

Clearly "instance" doesn't mean what I think it should mean.  Instead, it gives the error message, which I do not understand.

```
Could not deduce (r ~ Int)
from the context (IntClass r)
  bound by the type signature for intToIntClass  :: IntClass r => Int -> r
  at f.hs:10:1-16
  `r' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for intToIntClass  :: IntClass r => Int -> r
      at f.hs:10:1
In the expression: x
In an equation for `intToIntClass t': intToIntClass  x = x
```

Comment: The `(r ~ Int)` part of the top line in the error message means "Could not deduce type r is the same type as Int". `~` (tilde) means _type equality_ which once you are used to it is fine, but if this is the first time you've seen it then it's a bit bizarre. Using the more natural `=` for type equality would make Haskell's syntax ambiguous when it is used in programs rather than error messages.

Answer (score 14):

The signature

```
intToIntClass  :: (IntClass r) => Int -> r
```

means that `intToIntClass` can produce a value of whichever type the caller wants, as long as that type belongs to `IntClass`. But the implementation can only produce `Int` values.

It doesn't help that `Int` is - so far - the only instance, as far as the compiler is concerned, there may be more instances defined in other modules, so the compiler can't accept a method that produces only `Int`s.

Answer (score 9):

The function you wrote says, "Give me something, and I will give it back to you." The type you wrote says, "I can convert an `Int` into any type you the caller would like, as long as that type is an instance of the `IntClass` typeclass."

When we put those together, we have a function that will take an `Int` from the caller, and give it straight back. Except that when that very same `Int` is returned, it will be a value of any type the caller would like as long as that type is a member of the `IntClass` typeclass. How can the input go from being an `Int` to any (constrained) type the caller would like? It can't. Since the input is given straight back, the return type must be the same as the argument type. The type checker infers this from your code, but then can't reconcile that inference with you naming the output type `r`. The type checker wants to work with you on this, but can't be sure that `r` is the same thing as `Int` given the sole hypothesis that `r` is an instance of the `IntClass` typeclass.

A function rather like the one you wrote is `fromInteger`, found in the `Num` typeclass. If you want to talk about all types that you can construct based on an `Int`, then this should be a method of your typeclass. Something like:

```
class IntClass a where
  intToIntClass :: Int -> a
```

You would define this method for every type that you want to be an instance of `IntClass`, and would have your desired type of `intToIntClass :: IntClass r => Int -> r`. This return type polymorphism depends critically on each participating type having an appropriate definition of `intToIntClass`.

Answer (score 4):

Your typeclass is fine. For example, this works:

```
intId :: IntClass r => r -> r
intId = id
```

The problem is, `intToIntClass`'s type signature says it maps from `Int` to *any* member of `IntClass`. The compiler can't prove that `Int` is the *only* member of `IntClass`, and so since the body of `intToIntClass` rigidly returns `Int`, it's not polymorphic enough.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  My mistake was in thinking that the function signature was doing something like an interface cast in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

To further clarify, let's say I use your module alongside a new instance:

```
instance IntClass Integer
```

Then your implementation of of `intToIntClass` also promises to have type `(IntClass Integer => Int -> Integer)`.  But your implementation conflicts with this.  The compiler assumes type classes are "open", meaning that

1. new instances might appear in the future, and
2. today's code must not change behaviour in such a future

Thus the compiler sees that today the only instance is for `Int` but it cannot assume that this will stay true in the future.

The combination of (1.) and (2.) makes thinking and reasoning about Haskell code much easier.  There are far fewer caveats when you know today's new instance cannot screw up yesterday's code and that today's code is safe from tomorrow's new instance.